# Q: How to match App Engine user's credentials with IAM?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I would like to have an app deployed in App Engine to display information which are stored in BigQuery or Cloud Storage, but only if the user is authenticated in the webapp AND its permissions as set in IAM allow it.

So far, I can authenticate a user in App Engine through "Google Sign-In" as seen in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/, but those credentials don't seem to relate to those that are set in Cloud IAM.

I've seen how to set credentials for App Engine as a whole though a service account, but that seems to wide.

What I really want is to authenticate users on the web app, and then let IAM decide if those users are allowed to access data or not.

How would you proceed to do that?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

The [authenticating as an end user GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user#granting_and_limiting_access_to_project_resources) explains how to limit access to the project's resources using Cloud IAM. It also has a short example about authenticating an end user to call the BigQuery API.

Comment: I think you're pointing me in the right direction, but the code sample mentions launching a browser and such, which seems appropriate for a CLI tool, but not really for an App Engine hosted webapp... What am I missing here? Thanks